# How to DRY common actions in ASP.NET Controllers that inherit from different base classes?

Tags: c#

Let's say I have 2 controllers:

```
public class FirstController : FirstBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public object Get()
    {
        return new { Name = "John" };
    }
}


public class SecondController : SecondBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public object Get()
    {
        return new { Name = "John" };
    }
}
```

As you can see, they both inherit from different classes. But they both also have a shared method that can be shared between them.

Since C# does not support composition (no multiple inheritance) is there any options for me to DRY that method?

P.S. I know default members in interfaces might be a solution. But that's too limited for generic classes and for when it comes to IoC and DI.

Comment: Controller is for grouping end points together. A better approach is to move business away from controllers all together

Comment: @Eldar where is the business in the OP's code example?

Comment: @SaeedNeamati it's between the lines in the question and sounds like yelling to me. Of course, It would be better that OP gives more context about it.

Comment: @Eldar, no I don't yell at you. I just don't see any code here that can be labeled as **business code**. That's why I asked.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati I am not telling that you are yelling at me the question is. See the answer below it explains my above comment.

Answer (score 1):

[Composition is not an equivalent](https://code-maze.com/csharp-composition-vs-inheritance/) to inheritance. The inheritance model is denoted as being an "is - a" relationship and composition is denoted as being a "has - a" relation ship between classes. And you should not use inheritance just for code reuse.

You should separate your logic in different class and composition in .net. Then you can use it in controllers as a dependency with a [dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection):

```
public class UserService
{
    public object GetUser() => new { Name = "John" };
}

public class FirstController : FirstBase
{
    private readonly UserService userService;
    public FirstController(UserService userService)
    {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public object Get() => userService.GetUser();
}


public class SecondController : SecondBase
{
    private readonly UserService userService;
    public SecondController(UserService userService)
    {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public object Get() => userService.GetUser();
}
```

.NET supports the dependency injection (DI) software design pattern, which is a technique for achieving Inversion of Control (IoC) between classes and their dependencies. Dependency injection in .NET is a built-in part of the framework, along with configuration, logging, and the options pattern.

A dependency is an object that another object depends on.

Note that dependency injection is related to interfaces and abstractions, so it is important to use it when you use DI. It's a part of SOLID principles. Interfaces provide a level of abstraction from the concrete implementation, making it easier to swap out implementations and allowing for greater flexibility and reusability and easier testing with mocks.

You need to [register your dependencies in DI-container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addscoped?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0):

```
// use AddScoped to add TestRepo to DI-container
builder.Services.AddScoped<UserService>();
```

Finally understanding the life cycle of dependency injection is very important in ASP.Net (Core) applications. Transient objects are always different; a new instance is provided to every controller and every service. Scoped objects are the same within a request, but different across different requests. Singleton objects are the same for every object and every request. You can learn more in .net tutorial "[Use dependency injection in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-usage)".

Comment: I argue that while this helps lessen the code, it does not DRY the code. You still have to write a lot of boilerplate code to reuse that `GetUser()` method. PHP has [traits](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) and it's a simple `use DriedLogic` line of code.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati traits is a cool principle but we have no built-in mechanism for traits in C#. You can use Fody https://blog.adamfurmanek.pl/2016/10/22/traits-in-c-part-1/ or other aspects or source generators.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati But there are many other questions. First, whether the two methods are really the same, given that they carry an additional routing function in the controllers. Second, whether we have organized the class hierarchy correctly and why exactly two controllers are inherited from different base classes. Perhaps the solution to the problem lies not in finding a way to implement one method, but in changing the architecture of the classes. Default members in interfaces is a suitable solution too. But I think that it's a workaround for your problem but not a "real" solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement default interface methods in Interface and implement that interface.

**Default Interface Methods**

The main idea of this new C# feature is a possibility to provide a default implementation of an interface’s method.

Realization in C# 8.0
In our example using C# 8.0 we’ll be able to implement it as follows:

```
interface IDeveloper
  {
      void LearnNewLanguage(string language, DateTime dueDate);
      void LearnNewLanguage(string language)
      {   
          // default implementation
          LearnNewLanguage(language, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(6));
      }
  }
```

For more details you can check: https://www.codejourney.net/csharp-8-default-interface-methods/